# VK JAVA SDK авторизация для сообществ по ключу сообщества

Tags: java, вконтакте

Привет.
Я основательно запутался в авторизации для чат-бота для сообществ.
Как мне удалось понять, сообщество можно авторизовать банально черех ключ сообщества. А вот метод для такой авторизации остаётся для меня загадкой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/access_token?f=2.%20%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) перечислены все способы получения ключа доступа для сообщества:

> Implicit flow. Для работы с API от имени сообщества в Javascript-приложениях и Standalone-клиентах (десктопных или мобильных).
>
> Authorization code flow. Для работы с API от имени сообщества с
>   серверной стороны Вашего сайта.
>
> В интерфейсе настроек сообщества. Для этого достаточно открыть раздел
>   «Управление сообществом» («Управление страницей», если у Вас публичная
>   страница), выбрать вкладку «Работа с API» и нажать «Создать ключ
>   доступа».